# Как передать имя кнопки button при клике на нее мышкой в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Подскажите, как присвоить а потом узнать имя кнопки button в Python?

На форму выводятся кнопки с рандомными числами, при нажатии на которых должно осуществляться какое-либо действие, для начала просто отображение позиции кнопки (i и j). Никак не получается.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Numbs")
window.geometry('820x620')
def click_button(i,j):
    print(i,j)

for i in range(50):
    for j in range(22):
        ch = randint(1, 9)
        btn(i,j) = Button(window, text=ch, font=("Terminal", 10), command=lambda: click_button(i,j))
        btn(i,j).grid(column=i, row=j)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Numbs")
window.geometry('820x620')
def click_button(i,j):
    print(i,j)

for i in range(50):
    for j in range(22):
        ch = randint(1, 9)
        btn = Button(window, text=ch, font=("Terminal", 10), command=lambda i=i, j=j: click_button(i,j))
        btn.grid(column=i, row=j)
window.mainloop()
```